# The callback that I am giving to my `start` function at `Animated` is not called

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The callback that I am giving to my `start` function at 
`Animated` is not called:

```
Animated.spring(this.position, { toValue: { x: side, y: 0 }, duration: 2000 })
    .start(() => console.log(9999999));
```

it does not show any error and just nothing happened. I was assuming to see the log after 2 seconds.

P.S. but the animation worked, I mean the `position` was set to value 0 and 0 it took 2 seconds.

EDIT:  WHEN I USE `Animated.timing` it works !!!!!

Comment: try changing `.start(() => console.log(9999999))` to `.start(() => {console.log(9999999)})`

Comment: @bennygenel  didn't work and regard less we should return the callback not just call it, right?

Comment: either way is just fine. Mine was just a test to see if its gonna work or not. If the animation is successfully running callback should run also.

Comment: @bennygenel  from what i see on my device, the animation is working, but how to make sure that it's tagged as successful?

Comment: [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#working-with-animations) says it fill run the callback with `{finished: true || false}`. I don't see anything wrong with your code so I don't really have any idea why its not firing.

Comment: @Docs what does it mean `says it fill run the callback with {finished: true || false}` ? where i can log that finished object to see if it's true or false?

Comment: `.start((result) => console.log(result.finished));`

Comment: I tried `.start((result) => console.log(result.finished));`  nothing logged